# Why isn't my simple map.find(x) working?

Tags: c++, debugging, dictionary, insert, find

When I try to use the `find()` of a `map` in my C++-program, the function doesn't seem to work as it's supposed to be.

Here's the code:

*the map is defined like this:*

```
std::map<std::string,ownObject*> objects;
```

*here's the code that isn't running*

```
void someClass::addTarget(std::string objectName, ownObject* object)
{
if (this->objects.find(objectName) != this->objects.end())
    this->objects.insert(std::pair<std::string,ownObject*>(objectName,object));
}
```

**My actual intention** is, to check, if there is already an entry with that name (first key of the map) and if not add it to the map.

Now for some reason he never get's inside the if-function (calling `insert()`). From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92cwhskb.aspx I got, that the return value of `find()` is either the element, that one is looking for - or if it isn't available it is `objects.end()`

**When debugging** the map objects already contains `<'a',anObject>`, then I try to add `<'b',anotherObject>`, but as I said he never gets to the `insert()` function and I don't see why.

As explained on the given homepage (actually tried with their if-question), this should actually work, so unfortunately I don't even know where the problem could be.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Note: You don't have to check for this. If the key already exists then it doesn't insert it.

Comment: I found out it this only works if first and second key match. So it is possible to add pairs like: `<'a',anotherObject>` and afterwards add `<'b',anotherObject>` too.

Comment: @user3085931: That's how `std::map` works. It only looks at the key to compare and order [key-value] pairs. The value is just along for the ride.

Comment: @Blastfurnace that's why I'm checking it with an `if()`

Comment: @user3085931: You seemed confused about Rapptz' comment and Matthieu M.'s answer. The keys in a `std::map` are guaranteed to be unique. If you try to `insert()` a duplicate key it won't be added and you can tell by the function's return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My actual intention is, to check, if there is already an entry with that name (first key of the map) and if not add it to the map.

Then you need (`==`):

```
void someClass::addTarget(std::string objectName, ownObject* object)
{
if (this->objects.find(objectName) == this->objects.end())
    this->objects.insert(std::pair<std::string,ownObject*>(objectName,object));
}
```

`std::map::find` will return `std::map::end` if a key is not found in the range. Thus, you need to check for equality.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by 40two, your boolean condition is reversed.

However, the very premise that you actually *need* to check does not hold. In C++, there are two ways to insert new values in a `map`:

- `insert`/`emplace`: inserts the key/value pair *if the key is not already present*
- `[]`: yields a reference to the value associated to the key, *creating a default value if necessary (that is, the key was not present to start with)*

Therefore, in your case:

```
this->objects.insert(std::make_pair(objectName, object));
```

is the simplest snippet to achieve your goal.

*Hint: note the use of `make_pair` which automatically deduces the type of its arguments so you do not have to repeat it.*

Comment: Later I try it with `make_pair`, but as mentioned in the comment of the top-post: I found out it's not reliable that all the entries of a map are unique.

Comment: @user3085931: I don't understand what you are talking about. `std::make_pair(objectName, object)` produces the *very same result* than `std::pair<std::string, ownObject*>(objectName, object)`, and this has *nothing* to do with uniqueness of keys in map (pairs can be used outside maps). Furthermore, maps *reliably* guarantee the uniqueness of **keys**. They do not guarantee the uniqueness of the key/value pair, or the uniqueness of value, by design... and neither do your `if` check, which only checks the presence of the key.

Comment: the string key comes from the `objects.Name()` and in my application it is unique by algorithm, the question is just to be sure one object isn't twice in the map, and can easily be found.